# How to configure Meteor.settings?

Tags: meteor, meteorite

I'm trying to find information about what kinds of configurations I can set in my settings.json. The docs mention this functionality but don't offer much more about how to use it and what kinds of things I can set.

http://docs.meteor.com/meteor_settings#meteor_settings

Answer (score 2):

This is for your own settings, so you can set whatever you want to. This is useful when you want to differentiate between several app instances. For example, on development / staging you want to display some debug information, but hide it in production — then in `Meteor.settings` you can set what environment you're using.

Comment: do I set it like this? `Meteor.settings = '{
 "public" : {
   "ga": {
     "account":"UA-126293-23'"
   }
 }
}`

Comment: The point of those is that you set them outside of your app. For development, you set them when starting the server: `meteor --settings '{"echo": true}'`, for production you set the `METEOR_SETTINGS` env variable.